# Equivalent of python "help()" in go?

Tags: go

what is the equivalent of python "help()" in go? , how I can get help about modules?

Comment: go help modules

Comment: You type `go doc import/path/of/package`. Read `go help doc`.

Comment: Thank you this is what a need.

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation:

Latest HTML documentation for modules on golang.org

Run go help modules for more about modules. (This is the main entry point for modules topics via go help)

Run go help mod for more about the go mod command.

Run go help module-get for more about the behavior of go get when in module-aware mode.

Run go help goproxy for more about the module proxy, including a pure file-based option via a file:/// URL.

From the GitHub of Golang: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules